# Group id equals to 'me' and he's not a guid as expected

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to find my group id for report.

but from some reason in the URL of the report, the group id is just 'me' and not a guid as expected.

https://app.powerbi.com/groups/**me**/reports/**********/ReportSection

Why? And how can I find my group id?

Comment: As Andrey suggested, you can create new workspace in Power BI service account if you have got license or you can try using 2 months of trail period license to create new workspace. Post to that publish your report from dekstop to that new worksapce. Here you can get group id.

Answer (score 4):

This means that your report is published in `My workspace`, not in a group. `My workspace` is a special workspace, just for you, and resources published there can't be shared with others (except public sharing "[Publish to web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web)"). This is the only workspace available for Free accounts, unless there is a dedicated capacity (Power BI Premium or Power BI Embedded) assigned to it.

For more information you can take a look at [Create classic workspaces in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-create-workspaces) and [Organize work in the new workspaces in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-new-workspaces).